# How to make dynamic views with ionic angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic framework for my new application.

I have an issue, I want to know how it would be possible to insert views dynimacally.

I make a request to the server requesting news, the response in in JSON which look like :

```
{
"title":"news 1",
"image":"http://www.server.com/news_image1.png",
"description":"news_description"
},
{
"title":"news 2",
"image":"http://www.server.com/news_image2.png",
"description":"news_description"
},
{
"title":"news 3",
"image":"http://www.server.com/news_image3.png",
"description":"news_description"
}
```

I want to insert data dynmaically to the ion-view and be able to swipe between the news like the image below :

[image: APP]

So if you just have an idea how can that be possible !

Answer (score 0):

You could do a slide box and the use a ng-repeat to dynamically create slides. Although if you are making a bunch of slides i would use collection repeat. Check out slide boxes here http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/ . and ng-repeat and collectio-repeat here and here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat ,  http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/

Comment: so you would end of with one view, you would not even have to make dynamic views (which can get very crazy very fast, I have done it before and we ditched it)